# clearinterval with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, intervals

I have make a animation with a interval. This is my script:

```
var count = 0;
var countSecond = -40;
function arrowAnimation() {
    if (count > 40) {
        clearInterval();
    }
    $('.list-what-we-do .arrow').css({
        top: (count++) + 'px'
    });
}
function arrowAnimationSecond() {
    if (countSecond > 0) {
        clearInterval();
    }
    $('.list-what-we-do .arrow').css({
        right: (countSecond++) + 'px'
    });
}

setInterval(arrowAnimation, 5);
setInterval(arrowAnimationSecond, 5);
```

Now my question. How can i stop the interval. I used clearInterval. But that is not working. How can i fix this? Thanks for helping!

Comment: you are not capturing the return value from set interval and using that as an arguement for clear interval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` the return value is a reference; you pass this reference to `clearInterval` to cancel.

```
var foo = setTimeout(...);
clearTimeout(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the return value of the `setInterval` method to a variable

Then you can later clear it using `clearInterval`

```
var count = 0;
var countSecond = -40;

var interval = setInterval(arrowAnimation, 5);
var secondInterval = setInterval(arrowAnimationSecond, 5);

function arrowAnimation() {
    if (count > 40) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    $('.list-what-we-do .arrow').css({
        top: (count++) + 'px'
    });
}
function arrowAnimationSecond() {
    if (countSecond > 0) {
        clearInterval(secondInterval);
    }
    $('.list-what-we-do .arrow').css({
        right: (countSecond++) + 'px'
    });
}
```